# program settings are not updating

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created my c# winforms application and in properties, settings.settings I have declared a string as "user". when I first run the application I could read it using the following code successfully:

```
string user = Properties.Settings.Default.Username;
```

I can save new values for Username and read them again in code. BUT when I change the value in settings.settings and start my program with debugging (e.g. change it to "NoLiver"), it doesnt use the new text, it still reads it as "user" not "NoLiver". I dont understand why this is happening as my other program didnt do this.

Please can someone explain whats going on? Im not sure if you need any other information, but ask if you need any.

Comment: Are you calling `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();`?

Comment: I do when I save it during code and it works fine. Im talking when I change it in visual studio while the program isnt running

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is likely happening is the setting is a User Scoped setting instead of an Application Scoped setting. When you have a User Scoped setting the value in settings is only the *default* value, if you ran your program an a `user.config` file got generated for the user it will read the current value from the `user.config` file.

You have two options, change `Username` to be a application scoped setting or change the version number of your assembly, this will cause a new setting file to be generated and it will go back to the default values (If you don't want it to go back to the default values call `Upgrade()` on your settings class once and it will check for older versions and copy the settings over from the previous version of the program)

**EDIT:** You do have one more option, if this is just for debugging click the `Synchronize` button in Settings.settings, this will delete the user setting file from your hard drive and it will just use the default values again next time you run the program.

[image]

Comment: It has to be user scopped as it can be changed during runtime (I havent written the code to do it yet hence trying to do it this way)

Comment: In that case you need to change the version number of your assembly so it forces a new user settings file to be generated, then just don't call `Upgrade()` on it.

Comment: How do I change the version number? also I need it to be version 1.0 like it is now. Is here any other way around it?

Comment: Thanks but when I did this I got "No user.config files were found in any of the following locations: "

Comment: Are you running the program via ClickOnce? I ran in to a similar problem where it was not deleting the settings file of a clickonce app. You might need to delete it by hand, get the value of `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal).FilePath` from your program while it is running to see which file you have to delete. Deleting that file will do what clicking Synchronize would have done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68437/discussion-between-noliver92-and-scott-chamberlain).